# I want to change the contents in the container according to the selected item in the dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**this is my cod**

**This is the list that i created....**

```
final List<ThisDaysItems> daysMealList = [
  ThisDaysItems(
      dayName: "Monday",
      breakfast: "Upma & kadala curry",
      lunch: "Rice & Fish fry",
      snacks: "Bun & tea",
      dinner: "Rice & Chicken curry"),
  ThisDaysItems(
      dayName: "Tuesday",
      breakfast: "Upma & kadala curry",
      lunch: "Rice & Fish fry",
      snacks: "Bun & tea",
      dinner: "Rice & Chicken curry"),
];
```

**This is the Dropdown I am  using..**

```
AwesomeDropDown(
  dropDownList: const [
    "Monday",
    ...
  ],
  selectedItem: valueChoose,
  onDropDownItemClick: (selectedItem) {
    setState(() {
      valueChoose = selectedItem;
    });
    if (valueChoose == "Monday") {
      setState(() {
        itemName = daysMealList[0];
      });
    } else if (valueChoose == "Tuesday") {
      setState(() {
        itemName = daysMealList[1];
      });
    }
    print(itemName.toString());
  },
),
```

**this is the Listview.builder that I used to list. and in the listview, Mealdaylist is a refactored widget**

```
 ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return MealDayList(
              dayName: itemName.dayName,
              breakfast: itemName.breakfast,
              lunch: itemName.lunch,
              snacks: itemName.snacks,
              dinner: itemName.dinner);
        },
        itemCount: 1,
      ),
    ),
```

I want to update contents(that from the list) according to the day selected in the dropdown list

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWIFB.jpg)

pls help..

Answer (score 0):

simply use `setState(() {itemIndex = 1;});`. Then you can select the content above with whatever your data is like `Text(meal[itemIndex].title)`. Does this answer your question, it is a bit vague about your precise issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without a running snippet, but you can do the following:

use `.where()` on your list to filter for the selected day:

```dart
final selectedDay = daysMealList
                      .firstWhere((element) => element.dayName == value);
```

And then return this in the `ListView.builder()`